# Exclude imports from coverage in Python

Tags: python-3.x, coverage.py, coveralls

At the moment, I have 32% coverage of my library when testing my code using `coverage`, due to `coverage`, measuring coverage of e.g. `numpy`, `scipy`, and other imported Python libraries.
The command I am using is

```
coverage run -m pytest -v tests/
```

Is there a way to exclude running test coverage for imported packages?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution through the `--source` option in `coverage`:

```
coverage run --source ./ -m pytest -v tests/
```

where `./` is the current and only directory I want to include in the report.